# Small query regarding win32com.client

Tags: python, unix, win32com

I wanted to know whether `win32com.client` package be used in an python app if I want to run that application in the Unix server. My goal is to set a cron in the unix server to automate some mail related task using `win32com.client`. All I want to know is that will this whole `win32com` will work smoothly in the Unix server.

Answer (score 0):

No. `win32com` can only be installed and used on a Windows OS.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one. You will need to either port the Python code to platform-independent code or find some equivalent replacement that provides the specific functionality required from pywin32.

**BUT**

Tricky Way:

1) compile your .py file to .exe file with [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/)

2) install [wine](https://www.winehq.org/) on your linux

3) run your python applictaion with pywin32 pcakage on linux and enjoy it